Wrapping a pointer to device-side memory that was returned from a pybind11 module in a PyTorch Tensor
I have a C++ library that runs kernels on GPUs (it uses Kokkos). I would like to expose this in python and couple it with PyTorch, so I am using pybind11.
I would like to avoid adding a dependency on the PyTorch C++ API to my library so I am attempting to simply pass pointers between the C++/Python interface.
I have examples here:
C++-code:
https://github.com/jtchilders/python_kokkos_tests/blob/main/tensor_example.cpp
Python Code:
https://github.com/jtchilders/python_kokkos_tests/blob/main/tensor_example.py
I succeed at filling a PyTorch Tensor and passing it into the pybind11 function via:
tensor = torch.randn(10, device='cuda')
result = tenex.process_tensor(tensor.data_ptr(), tensor.size(0))

The function in C++:
TensorData process_tensor(uintptr_t input_data_ptr, std::size_t size){

   // Convert uintptr_t back to float* after passing from Python
   float* actual_data_ptr = reinterpret_cast<float*>(input_data_ptr);

   // Create an unmanaged Kokkos view from the raw pointer that points at the device
   Kokkos::View<float*, Kokkos::DefaultExecutionSpace, Kokkos::MemoryTraits<Kokkos::Unmanaged>> input_view(actual_data_ptr, size);

   // Allocate device-side memory to hold the output using Kokkos
   float* output_data_ptr = static_cast<float*>(Kokkos::kokkos_malloc<Kokkos::DefaultExecutionSpace>(size * sizeof(float)));

   // Create an unmanaged Kokkos view for the output that wraps the created memory
   Kokkos::View<float*, Kokkos::DefaultExecutionSpace, Kokkos::MemoryTraits<Kokkos::Unmanaged>> output_view(output_data_ptr, size);
   
   // the reason to use unmanaged views is to avoid Kokkos from 
   // trying to clean up the memory automatically

   // Perform operations on the GPU
   Kokkos::parallel_for("scale_data", Kokkos::RangePolicy<Kokkos::Cuda>(0, size), KOKKOS_LAMBDA(const int i) {
      output_view(i) = input_view(i) * 2.0f;  // Example operation
   });

   Kokkos::fence();  // Ensure Kokkos operations are completed

   // Return the output data pointer as uintptr_t
   TensorData result; // this is just a struct to hold the pointer and array size
   result.data_ptr = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(output_view.data());
   result.size = size;

   return result;
}

How can I create a PyTorch Tensor from a pointer & size of array?
Keep performance in mind. All the steps I've taken try to avoid unnecessary host/device copies which slow things down, so I want the PyTorch Tensor to simply take ownership of the device-memory pointed to by the array. Ideally it would also destroy the memory at the end of the python code.

Does this answer your question? How do I cast a raw pointer to a pytorch tensor of a specific shape? It uses ctypes instead of pybind11 though.

Thanks @paleonix I tried using the second answer and It fails with an error on torch.as_tensor(...); see here:
TypeError: object of type 'LP_c_float' has no len()```

presumably torch is trying to set the length of the tensor by querying the object I passed it which is of type <class '__main__.LP_c_float'> after the ctype conversion.

The first answer almost works, but torch.frombuffer  doesn't support using device-side buffers. If I could find a way to covertly change the device property for the tensor, then it might work.

Then I don't see a way of not using the C++ interface, torch::from_blob in particular like here or maybe even better creating a Kokkos view of an existing torch::Tensor for output.

See also Custom C++ and CUDA Extensions.

Yeah, I think I am slowly coming to that conclusion myself. I was trying to avoid making the C++ library dependent on another library. Thanks for the help @paleonix

I think the best practice is to keep your library kernel-only so it only deals with c-type pointers, and then write another pytorch cuda extension that uses pytorch c++ interface to call your apis
